# How to redefine a C++ #define macro using information from the macro itself?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to redefine a C++ #define macro using information from the macro itself?  I tried the code below, but because of the way the macros are evaluated the output was not what I expected.

```
#include <iostream>

#define FINAL_DEFINE "ABC"
#define NEW_DEFINE FINAL_DEFINE "DEF" // Want ABCDEF

#undef FINAL_DEFINE
#define FINAL_DEFINE NEW_DEFINE // Want ABCDEF, but get empty?


int main ()
{
    std::cout << FINAL_DEFINE << std::endl; // Want ABCDEF, but doesn't compile.
}
```

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear.  Let me know if it's still ambiguous.

Comment: Basically: not possible, as Chris Dodd's answer explains.  As a workaround you'll have to use a different name for the intermediate define (FINAL_DEFINE on the first 2 lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros in macro bodies are *never* expanded when the macro is defined -- only when the macro is used.  That means that the definition of `NEW_DEFINE` is *not* `"ABC" "DEF"`, it is exactly what appears on the #define line: `FINAL_DEFINE "DEF"`.

So when you use `FINAL_DEFINE`, that gets expanded to `NEW_DEFINE` which then gets expanded to `FINAL_DEFINE "DEF"`.  At this point it will not recursively expand `FINAL_DEFINE` (as that would lead to an infinite loop) so no more expansion occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports `push_macro` & `pop_macro` pragma directives, you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define FINAL_DEFINE "ABC"
#define NEW_DEFINE FINAL_DEFINE "DEF"

int main ()
{
    std::cout << FINAL_DEFINE << std::endl; // Output ABC

    #pragma push_macro("FINAL_DEFINE")
    #define FINAL_DEFINE "XXX"
    std::cout << NEW_DEFINE << std::endl; // Output XXXDEF
    #pragma pop_macro("FINAL_DEFINE")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After preprocessing all `FINAL_DEFINE` in the code will be replaced with the **last thing** it defined and then going to compiling step.

So you cannot redefine the macro like you want.

Your compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: Warning is not mean it' s ilegal, warning about macro redefined will help you a lot in big project when sometime same macros are define in different places.